# How to assign external json file as variable in other file

Tags: javascript, json

I currently have some Javascript on a page template which manages some JSON data. The way I have it configured currently, the JSON data is assigned to a variable right on the page template. What I would like to do is move the JSON to an external `.json` file and still be able to use my variable on the page template. Currently it looks like this:

```
var data = [{
    "fruit": "Apple",
    "size": "Large",
    "color": "Red"
}];
```

What I would like to do is create a file called `data.json` and then assign it as the data variable on my page template.

`data.json`:

```
{
    "fruit": "Apple",
    "size": "Large",
    "color": "Red"
}
```

Page template:

```
var data = 'data.json';
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: With `require("data.json")`?

Comment: @JeremyThille Can I do it without using `require`? This is not a node project, so I would have to load it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load your json in dynamic way using e.g. fetch

```js
async function start() {
  let url = 'my.json'
  var data = await (await fetch(url)).json();
  // ...
}

start();
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! Will accept in 3 min.

Comment: how to use "data" somewhere else in the code?

Comment: @galizien you can use this function in other async function (jjust add `return data` statement in the bottom of start function). In async function you should then call it as follows `let startData = await start()`

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski if i call it like you said, i am recieving an error "await is only valid in async functions and async generators"

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski so I can use my "data" only in other async function?

Comment: @galizien not only - you can also use it in nonasync function as Promise - because async function allways return Promise - as follows `start().then(data=> { console.log(data) });`. Don't forget that you operate on asynchronous code (however `asyn-await` magically make that it looks more like synchronous code)